# Incorrect subfigure identifier using hyperref and subbottom in the memoir class

Tags: hyperref, memoir, subfloats

All the subfigure identifiers (a,b,c,d,e, etc.) are out by one count when I reference subfigures in the memoir class using hyperref and subbottom. For example, Fig. 1b displays as Fig. 1a.

I honestly have no idea how to go about fixing this issue. I have searched online but have not found any similar issues. I'm not sure if this is relevant but I did not get this issue when I was running Windows 7 Professional. Since upgrading to Windows 10 (the university forced me too...) I have had this issue when compiling my thesis. This is the last thing I need to fix before I submit so any help would be much appreciated.

Please find a MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Creates hyperlinks in cross references
\newsubfloat{figure}  % Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \subbottom[Caption 1a]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig1a}} 
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \subbottom[Caption 1b]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig1b}} 
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \subbottom[Caption 1c]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-c}\label{fig1c}}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{tabular}
    \caption[This is a figure]{A figure showing three panels}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

Referencing the main figure works fine!
\begin{itemize}
    \item This should be Fig. 1.1 : Fig. \ref{fig1}
\end{itemize}

\noindent
Now try and reference the subfigures individually...
\begin{itemize}
    \item This should be Fig. 1.1a: Fig. \ref{fig1a}
    \item This should be Fig. 1.1b: Fig. \ref{fig1b}
    \item This should be Fig. 1.1c: Fig. \ref{fig1c}    
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong, the label should go into the `[...]` as in `\subbottom[Caption 1c\label{fig1c}]{...}`

Comment: Not your fault though, it was a typo in the manual that was fixed in the yet to be released next update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo in the manual, the `\label` goes into the optional argument not the actual contents.

This works just fine

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Creates hyperlinks in cross references
\newsubfloat{figure}  % Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \subbottom[Caption 1a\label{fig1a}]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}} 
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \subbottom[Caption 1b\label{fig1b}]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-b}} 
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \subbottom[Caption 1c\label{fig1c}]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{tabular}
    \caption[This is a figure]{A figure showing three panels}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

Referencing the main figure works fine!
\begin{itemize}
    \item This should be Fig. 1.1 : Fig. \ref{fig1}
\end{itemize}

\noindent
Now try and reference the subfigures individually...
\begin{itemize}
    \item This should be Fig. 1.1a: Fig. \ref{fig1a}
    \item This should be Fig. 1.1b: Fig. \ref{fig1b}
    \item This should be Fig. 1.1c: Fig. \ref{fig1c}    
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This has solved my problem.